# Mocking only one static method inside a class (junit4 and mockito)

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using junit and mockito to write my unit tests. I have the following class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static String methodA(String arg1) {
        return arg1 + methodB();
    }
    public static String methodB() {
        OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
        return OtherClass.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

I want to write a test for methodA, so I want to mock methodB. I first tried to do this by using mockStatic:

```
MockedStatic<SomeClass> someClassInst = mockStatic(SomeClass.class);
someClassInst.when(() -> SomeClass.methodB()).thenReturn("testStr");
someClassInst.when(() -> SomeClass.methodA(anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

But I just keep getting null when I call methodA in the test:

```
String result = SomeClass.methodA("test")
```

This line is giving me a nullpointer exception. And when I debug methodA, it is just directly going to the return line.

I'm not sure if there's anything wrong that I'm doing here. I tried using spy, but faced a lot more issues with that, so I was wondering if I can achieve what I want using mock

My dependencies for junit and mockito:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try removing mockito-core from pom.

Comment: Can you share all testing class? I suppose, this issue related with mockito to test-class connection.